# iOS11: UITableView spacing between content and keyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview, ios11

So my problem is relatively simple.

I created a test app with just 1 screen.
This screen is a `UINavigationController` with a `UITableViewController` as root view controller. The table view has 30 cells which have a `UITextField` added as subview. The `UINavigationController` is also showing the toolbar to demonstrate the problem better.

Now to my problem. I started this app on the iPhone X simulator and scrolled to the bottom. Then i tapped a `UITextField` to edit the text, entered some text and scrolled to the bottom again. And now there is the problem. The full keyboard height is added as bottom content inset, and as you know, since iOS11 there is the new `safeArea` from which the contentInset now is added. And as you now can already imagine, the contentInset is too big, because the keyboard height is also calculated from the screen edge and not the `safeArea` edge. For better understanding the problem look at the attached screenshot.

As you can see, the scroll bar and content is ending way too early! This huge spacing between the table view content and the keyboard should not be there! The bigger the `safeArea` on the bottom, the bigger the spacing gets.

[image: visualization of the problem]

Comment: but what do you want to solve? is that extra space your problem?

Comment: oh, yeah thats the problem, i'll add that to the description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple fixed this problem by themselves.
In iOS 11.1 (beta) the problem does not appear anymore.